# Package manager for windows - using multiple versions of Acrobat Reader on Windows

Tags: windows, package-manager

I would like to experiment with known vulnerabilities (and analyse so called *proof-of-concept* (PoC) files) in older versions of *Acrobat Reader* on *Windows Vista*, *Windows 7* and *Windows 10*. I will need multiple versions of *Acrobat Reader* simultaneously installed on my system so I can switch between them. Is there any good free Windows tool? The simplest solution would be of course to uninstall previous version of *Acrobat Reader* and then install another one.

On *Linux* exist e.g. [snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager)) or [nix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nix_package_manager). Is there something similar for *Windows*?

Answer (score 1):

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) has [packages](https://chocolatey.org/packages/adobereader/2019.010.20099) [for](https://chocolatey.org/packages/adobereader/2018.011.20063) [Acrobat](https://chocolatey.org/packages/adobereader/2015.007.20033.02) [Reader](https://chocolatey.org/packages/adobereader/10.0.1).

Comment: As I understand correctly it allows me to install multiple versions of Acrobat Reader on Windows at once?

Comment: @Awaaaaarghhh Yes (or at least should; I run Linux most of the time).